# Rails 5.2 belongs_to association not linking to parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have these models

```
class Version
  has_many :bids
end


class Bid
  belongs_to :version
end
```

in the console:

```
> bid = Bid.first
```

which returns

```
> #<Bid id: 8 version_id: 5, deleted_at: nil, created_at: "2018-09-06 00:32:32", updated_at: "2018-09-06 00:32:32", created_by_id: 3, updated_by_id: 3, selected: true>
```

but if i try to call the version it returns nil. the version is there though

```
> bid.version
> nil
> Version.find(bid.version_id)
> #<Version id: 5, effective_date: "2018-09-05 23:36:24", end_date: nil, created_at: "2018-09-05 23:36:24", updated_at: "2018-09-05 23:36:24", created_by_id: nil>
```

what is going on? what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Are those the complete models?

Comment: No, what else do you want to know?

Comment: I was not able to reproduce this, used Rails `5.2.0`.

Comment: Mainly whether you have any `default_scope`s, or whether you've defined a method in your `Bid` model named `version`. Regardless, it's good practice to provide as much info as you can. Chances are that something you assume to be unrelated, is related.

Comment: Comment out the extra code leaving the models as you posted them. Try in console. Then in comment some lines and test again, so on... You should find what’s wrong.   Don’t forget to `reload!` in console.

Comment: This sound like a naming collusion to me. `version` might be a method added by a gem that keeps track of model updates. Therefore did you add a `version` method to your model? Or do you use any additional gems in your models?

Comment: spickerman that's sort of what's going on, turns out `version` is an existing object method in rails. you pointed me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that `object.version` is an existing rails method. if i change the relationship to `belongs_to :pricing_version` the code works.
Anyone with this issue in the future just avoid naming their class `Version`